# Django, how to convert Python dict to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, django

In a Django app I have a dict created in a view and I want to use it in Javascript, but I get a syntax error

**views.py**

```
MY_TYPES = {
    'use_random': 0,
    'use_stages': 1,
    'use_import': 2,
    0: 'use_random',
    1: 'use_stages',
    2: 'use_import',
}


class Duo(View):
    url = 'duo/test_dict.html'

    def get(self, request, partner_pk):
        context = {
            'my_types': json.dumps(MY_TYPES),
        }
        return render(request, self.url, context)
```

**test_dict.html**

```
{% load static %}
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>`

{% block content %}
    <h1> Test dict</h1>

    <script>
        my_types = {{ my_types|safe }};
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/test_dict.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock content %}
```

**test_dict.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(my_types)
    console.log(JSON.parse(my_types))
});
```

Line 2 gives the output

> {0: "use_random", 1: "use_stages", 2: "use_import", use_random: 0, use_stages: 1, use_import: 2}

but throws the error in line 3

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but throws the error in line 3
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

The reason this happens is because it is no longer a *string* but a JSON blob. You should pass this as a string if you want `my_types` to be a string:

```
<script>
my_types = '{{ my_types|safe }}';
</script>
```

by adding quotes (`'…'`), you thus wrap it in a string.

But this is actually not necessary, if you write `my_types = {{ my_types|safe }};`, then `my_types` will already be a JavaScript dictionary, and then calling `JSON.parse(…)` makes thus no sense.

Note that JSON does *not* allow integers to be keys, so Python will convert the integer keys to their string counterparts.